# What's the point of using [:]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, append

I was looking at someone's solution to backtracking using the heap's algorithm using Python3 today. The solution is below:

```
def permute(self, nums):
    def backtrack(start, end):
        if start == end:
            ans.append(nums[:])
        for i in range(start, end):
            nums[start], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[start]
            backtrack(start+1, end)
            nums[start], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[start]

    ans = []
    backtrack(0, len(nums))
    return ans
```

Now I am looking at the line `ans.append(nums[:])`, What's the point of writing `nums[:]`? Won't writing `nums` function correctly?

Comment: One common reason is to make a *copy* of a list, instead of just getting a reference to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not the same because in the for loop you are mutating `nums`

```
 nums[start], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[start]
```

If you append a reference to `nums` to your answer rather than an independent copy, you will be mutating all the asnwer's sub-elements and end up with a list of identical permutations all reflecting the final value. You can simply try that and see the results:

```
def permute(nums):
    def backtrack(start, end):
        if start == end:
            ans.append(nums)
        for i in range(start, end):
            # changing sums which will be reflected in all
            # references to nums in the ans array
            nums[start], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[start]
            backtrack(start+1, end)
            nums[start], nums[i] = nums[i], nums[start]

    ans = []
    backtrack(0, len(nums))
    return ans

permute([1, 2, 3])
```

All the same:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

You can confirm they all point to the same object in memory:

```
l = permute([1, 2, 3])
[id(el) for el in l]

> [140539119291912, # all the same reference
   140539119291912,
   140539119291912,
   140539119291912,
   140539119291912,
   140539119291912]
```

By using `ans.append(nums[:])` you make a copy so further mutations of `nums` don't affect the combinations you already have.

Answer (score 7):

Consider the following

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [a]
>>> b[0].append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

As you can see, that modifying `b[0]` modifies `a`, because you have stored the object `a` in `b`, not just the values of `a`. Using `[:]` makes a copy of the list, so.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [a[:]]
>>> b[0].append(4)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
```

So the point is to pass the values, not the object itself.